# unaligned sequence labeling

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, natural-language

How to extract semantic slots like: person=”Obama”, attribute=”birthday” for questions“what is the birthday of Obama” and “when did Obama born”. As far as I know, models like CRF, RNN can’t label sentences which don’t contain slotvalue like “birthday” in “when did Obama born?”. What kind of model can I use?

Answer (score 1):

> How to extract semantic slots like: person=”Obama”, attribute=”birthday” for

The task is referred to as *slot filling*. Many models have been explored, e.g.:

- Vu, Ngoc Thang. "Sequential convolutional neural networks for slot filling in spoken language understanding." arXiv preprint arXiv:1606.07783 (2016). https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.07783
- Mesnil, Grégoire, Yann Dauphin, Kaisheng Yao, Yoshua Bengio, Li Deng, Dilek Hakkani-Tur, Xiaodong He et al. "Using recurrent neural networks for slot filling in spoken language understanding." IEEE/ACM Transactions on Audio, Speech, and Language Processing 23, no. 3 (2015): 530-539. https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/44628.pdf

There are some shared tasks that focus on it, e.g.:

- Dialog State Tracking Challenge (DSTC) http://www.colips.org/workshop/dstc4/